# Can I use a PayPal donation button in my Android app in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

My country is not supported by Google for a Merchant account so I can't publish paid apps. But I would like to get some donations from my users. I know that Google says in their policy that all payments must go through Google Play.

How about donations? Can I use a donation button, which links to PayPal to accept donations? Or can I use the PayPal Mobile Payment Libraries (MPL) to accept donations?

Comment: I'd love to know this too. I've heard of a couple isolated incidents where apps have been suspended do to use of a PayPal donation button but that was a long time ago and there seems to be a large amount of users implementing the PayPal MPL in their apps. That being said, I doubt Google's policies have changed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**I contacted them and they replied as below:**

> Thank you for contacting the Google Play Team.
>
> I see that your question is regarding accepting donations through
>   PayPal. Donations may only be collected within an app under certain
>   conditions:
>
> 1. Donations are only permitted for validated non-profit charitable organizations (for example, a validated 501(c)(3) charitable
>      organization or the local equivalent).
> 2. Donations must be facilitated via a web browser, and any collection must be made through a secure payment system.
>
> If you belong to an eligible charitable organization, please follow
>   these steps:
>
> 1. Attach a copy of your organization’s IRS determination letter or other acceptable proof in your reply to this notification. The
>      provided information must indicate your status as a charitable
>      organization.
> 2. Ensure your app only facilitates donations via a web browser as specified above.
> 3. Submit your app for review.
>
> Alternatively, if you are not a charitable organization, you must
>   remove the donation functionality from your app, or accept payment
>   through Google Play's in-app billing service or Paid app distribution
>   on the Play Store. You can learn more about in-app billing in our Help
>   Center: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html
>
> I hope this helps. Thank you for your support of Google Play.
>
> Regards, Bruce The Google Play Team

Comment: The word donation seems to be connected to charity 501c3 organizations. As it is tax deductable for example. Is there a way to call it differently and allow users to support the developer voluntarily that way?

Answer (score 5):

Google Play says **you can't** (unless you are a validated non-profit charitable organization).

However, you can try putting **the link to your website** into the app, where you have a **PayPal donation button** (along with other info about the app, of course). It doesn't seem to break the Google Play rules. But I wouldn't recommend naming this button "Donate". Maybe, "Support development of this app" would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

update 2017: This app no longer has the Paypal donation option

---

I just saw this app with PayPal donation option on the Play Store, but I'm not sure since when, maybe the guys at Google haven't seen the app yet. It is last updated one month ago...
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zdvdev.sef

The option is available in the menu and it opens up a link in the browser.

Comment: I also have a betting tips app and i receive payment via paypal. My app is still intact. but payments are handled by browser and not app itself

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, if you are not a charitable organization, you must remove the donation functionality from your app, or accept payment through Google Play's in-app billing service or Paid app distribution on the Play Store.

But that part. or accept payment through googles inapp billing. Does that mean yes or no? just can't use third party services for the donation without legit donation foundation

Answer (score -6):

yes you can use PayPal services in your app
there are many apps currently using it
example-
check the link 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.apporiginal.creditcall

Comment: I've sent email to Google. Even them can't confirm that it is allowed to use PayPal or not. And I can't try out the linked app without writing in my phone number, which I don't want to do. Do you have any proof that it's allowed? And if MPL is allowed, opening a browser window to PayPay is allowed too, isn't it?

Comment: well i don't have any kind of proof but i have seen in many such apps and if it is not allowed then why are these apps still surfacing on the play store?

Comment: Careful, Google Play has suspended several apps (including my own) for having a PayPal donate button inside the app (even though it is not required / gives no benefit to the user) since they are not getting a share of the profits. It is against their Distribution Agreement. madhur.co.in/blog/2014/05/26/hermesremoved.html