# How can I accept volunteer payment without a donation button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, paypal, in-app-purchase

I've had a mobile game I've made with Unity ready to release for coming up on a year. I've been procrastinating horribly in part because I'm struggling on how to monetize it.

I want to release the game for free, and only make money off optional skins for the characters. There is a menu for new skins. I want each skin to be a pay-what-you-want (even $0), but open up the payment window with suggested pricing for some of the shinier ones. Once the user has entered their amount, the skin is unlocked.

The easiest way I can think of to do this is through PayPal donation buttons. I would store all assets locally, and unlock them once their button was pressed. However Google will only allow this type of button if I'm a verified non-profit, which I am not. [I don't think Google allows other PayPal buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371309/3263864). I also know for a fact that it violates Apple's terms of service.

How can I implement a cross platform 'pay what you want' system for in-app purchases that doesn't violate ToS for Apple or Google? I will accept a Unity specific answer or a more general one.

Comment: Have you considered having several pricing tiers? Maybe even hook them up to a slider that snaps to discrete price points. Also, a piece of highly opinionated advice: avoid PayPal like the plague for digital good payments.

Answer (score 1):

Some apps, most recently [PCalc](http://www.pcalc.com), use a "Tip jar" for donations, using in app purchases with preset amounts, which doesn't violate Apple's TOS.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a Unity specific answer / tutorial here

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

It should be trivial to add functionality for the user to select what they wish to pay; Either through a text field or slider bar.