# Is a donation button in an Android app compliant with Google's rules?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have uploaded an app on Google Play store which got rejected because I have a PayPal donation button in it. The exact reason is: "Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Payments policy".

I'm reading **[Play Console's Payments policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738/)**, but I don't see anywhere mentioned that in-app donation are prohibited.

Am I missing something?

Comment: isn't it in rule 4? `apps may not lead users to a payment method other than Google Play's billing system`

Comment: *Play-distributed apps requiring or accepting payment for access to in-app features or services, including any app functionality, digital content or goods (collectively “in-app purchases”), must use Google Play’s billing system for those transactions unless Section 3 or Section 8 applies.* Rule 2 refers to purchases. Does this include donations?

Answer (score 0):

You can accept donation if you meet the criteria below

```
1) Donations are only permitted for validated non-profit charitable organizations (for example, a validated 501(c)(3) charitable organization or the local equivalent).

2) Donations must be facilitated via a web browser, and any collection must be made through a secure payment system.
```

And, if you're not charitable organization then you must remove the donation functionality from your app, or accept payment through Google Play's in-app billing service. For more about in-app billing see [Help Center](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)

For more information about Android in app donations [Android in app donations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270564/android-in-app-donations)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where exactly do they mention this rule regarding donations?

Comment: check source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783664/can-i-use-a-paypal-donation-button-in-my-android-app-in-google-play